# Extract strings using regular expressions in Delphi

Tags: regex, delphi

I have HTML where I need to collect all the content that has a particular format, e.g. get everything that is in the `00.000.000/0000-00` or `XX.YYY.IIO/KKKK-LL` formats.

Would use of regular expressions be the best way to accomplish this, or how else can I accomplish this?

Comment: I could do what I wanted with this: [0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2}

Comment: That won't match `XX.YYY.IIO/KKKK-LL`. [`.{2}\..{3}\..{3}\/.{4}-.{2}`](http://regexr.com/3bc4i) ?

Comment: And your use of optional for those dot, slash and hyphen separators is wrong. You would be matching also `00000000000000` with such pattern.

Comment: Ugh! Yet another "how do I parse HTML/XML with regular expressions" question. Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/62576 for one of many posts about why you've chosen the wrong tool for the job, and then use a DOM parser to make your life (and the lives of others who may have to maintain your code) much easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 he comes

Comment: Hmmm... he is not really parsing the HTML itself, i.e. the tags etc. He is merely looking in a text that happens to be HTML for the pattern. But if I understand it right, the XX.YYY etc. are merely the mask he is looking for (similar to YYYY.MM.DD etc.). Then `\d{2} etc...`would probably be a solution.

Comment: @David: a classic. And quite a lot of work to get the formatting that way.

Comment: @Rudy, digit would not match the alpha chars from the latter example in the question. You can try it in my carrot example.

Comment: As I said, ISTM the alpha chars are only the mask he/she is trying to match. IOW, the first two digits form the `XX` part, the next three digits the `YYY` part, the `II0` stands for the `II` part which consists of two digits followed by `0`, etc.

Comment: @Rudy, if they are format strings, not value examples, then we don't know their definition, hence we could only guess here.

Comment: AFAICT, he wants to look for strings in that format. So something like `\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}0/\d{4}-\d{2}`. Should not be too hard to do. How the parts of the match are used (what the digits stand for) is not the problem here.

Comment: FWIW, the different parts (XX, YYY, etc.) could be captured separately, making the parsing a lot easier.

Comment: @DarkDucke Could you define what you mean by XX.YYY.IIO/KKKK-LL, to avoid misconception? I thouth you want also accept letters

Comment: @m.cekiera, I meant any characters within this mask
"nn.nnn.nnn/nnnn-nn", where nn can be alphanumeric, I've got when it's just numbers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a pattern that will match:

```
xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx
```

where `x` is only an alphanumeric char (that is `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`), then you can use this pattern:

```regex
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}
```

You can try it in [this example](http://regexr.com/3bcb4).

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
\w{2}\.\w{3}\.\w{3}\/\w{4}-\w{2}
```